# Smart and efficient way to implement in app purchases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit

I have spend past few days researching, looking and trying various ways to implement in app purchases in my iOs app. However, even though there are some quite ok blogs regarding this matter, I still could not complete my mission 100 percent. First, let me tell me what I have been trying to do:

First, I would like to implement a consumables store in my sprite kit scene (I am using objective c). Then, with these consumables, user could buy stuff, such as new levels, new characters, etc. Long story short - a very typical way of in app purchasing. However, I am making my app so it is available on iPhone 4s, 5/5s, 6/6plus and iPad. For all the images which come when user first downloads the app I use texture atlas and append the right folder name ending depending on the screen height. However, I want to keep my app size below 50mb, so I cant add to much files in texture atlas.

Now, I have researched allot on the matter described above, and since it is quite typical in app purchasing situation, I thought that this topic will benefit not me only. So here is what I learned so far:

1) Load product identifiers 
2) Request product info
3) Display products
4) Issue payment request
5) Process transaction results
6) Unlock/update the content
7) Finish transaction

I did find enough information so I could update my consumable, which happen to be collectable, amount by statically loading product indentifiers. The questions I still have are:

1. Creating the  .plist file for my products. I have zero experience with that. I know that I should create them on a server so it takes less space on my app. But how, what kind of server I should chose, after I have the server, what follows?
2. Lets say I successfully managed to add consumables purchase. I can use those consumables to buy extra stuff. How do I store that extra stuff on the server, how do I download it after pressing buy and how do I activate it in my sprite kit game?
3. Am I still missing something?
4. Is there a away to not have texture atlas for all devices but to download only the one user needs when he first opens the game?

Thats the problems I am facing right now, and I am sure there will be plenty after me, desperately trying to set up in game store and spending hours and days on that matter. It would be nice to have a nice, practical reference on IAP on the vast broadness of the internet, hence, I also hope that this question will receive not only answers but also the comments and suggestions on each of the steps I described above.

LP

Comment: Why do you want to use a server?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question description, I dont want my app to take more than 50Mb. Why? If it does, according to some references, user will not be able to download it without wifi connection. Also, the less space app takes, the less user has to download and hence, the less he spends on his cellular network charges, which is nice.

Comment: Fair enough but using a server for IAP still baffles me. You are really just setting properties when making IAP. For example, inventory items like "gold" you would set your gold's property value. Unless your IAP includes something like new enemies, where you have to download a lot of new animation sequences, I can't see why you would want to use your own server.

Comment: Exactly. I understand that creating the server just for the coins is nonsense. However, I would like to use that server to store my: Texture atlas, where I have my initial game settings, such as background png, player png and etc. When user first launches the app, I want the app to download required atlas for that screen size, instead of downloading all 5. Also, I would like to use server to store those purchases a user can make if he spends his "stars". If something costs 100 stars, he spends it and then downloads that content for specific device type. Hope this makes me more clear.

Comment: You are gambling that the user always has an internet connection when using your game. If for some reason the user does not, you might put the user in a position that will severely restrict the game play and cause some frustration. Having said that, I wish you luck.

Comment: What about downloading it for the first time time and then saving it to the app directory so it is reusable on that device each time? Thats my plan

Comment: I'd say server is helpful for maintaining list of IAPs(app can download it after start or whenever needed so that addition of new IAPs don't require app update), for checking IAP receipts and maybe for some content storing. Also it may be needed for recurring subscriptions(probably not in this case).

Answer (score 0):

With my experience on creating an Mobile iPhone POS App,

I can suggest you the followings:

**Note:** This is not an experience gained from implementing a SpritKit Game! :-)

1. If you wish to have a server to store the details regarding each consumable, which makes you capable of customizing or adding new consumable items through a Web back-end to the game, then simply implement a web API and integrate it to your Game.
2. As you said, you should be able to show a set of consumables, load the list of consumables (through that Web API you created) as a JSON file which contains the details regarding each consumable, like Consumable name, Expiration after buying it, How much it is and image path of the server to download it(if you wish to show an image for each consumable) etc. Then using that information in that JSON file you can implement a App Syncing session whenever there are any new Consumables(update is available) then download all the required images(full sizes or thumbnails or as you wish).

In the POS App what I did are as follows:

Before going to the Home Screen, I request from the server the list of products. in that there are following info of each product, product name, description, price, code, SKU, and full image, thumbnail image. So at first at the Syncing screen before the Home Screen, on the App's first launch it get the list of Product details and stores them in the Apps local SQLite DB, and then proceeds to the home screen! There on App checks if there are any updates on the Syncing screen, else proceeds to home as mentioned above.

However I show the products on a table view, and with pre-downloaded thumbnail images. And whenever the use clicks on that row of a product, it goes to the Detail view, and at that time, using the full image name or path, I download it and keep it saved. I check each time before downloading those images, if I have downloaded them before!

Hope these two suggestions and information will be helpful to you.

**FYI:**

- Easy Web API Integration using [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/). And [GitHub link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
- [Quick JSON Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)
- And following is another link I read in LinkedIn regarding [In-App Purchasing](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-best-way-do-121874.S.5977280052008673284?view=&item=5977280052008673284&type=member&gid=121874&trk=eml-b2_anet_digest-hero-4-hero-disc-disc-0&midToken=AQG7DVnJbUyJrw&fromEmail=fromEmail&ut=1jvu3t0dsstSE1).